# Bing is popping. How shall I fix it?

Tags: virus, popups, bing

Whenever I google something. Bing automatically searches the same thing. Please help me how shall I fix it. It appears like this:

[image: A screenshot of an active Bing tab open next to a Google tab, with the same phrase searched on both.]

Comment: When did this start happening? Did you install or run any new software recently? Try disabling all browser extensions.

Comment: THANK god its happening to some one else.
I have narrrowed it down to a location from where this is getting loaded even if I delete the folder, it is recreated again it loades an extenstion called wHostLink 0.26 Link Host

Comment: @Smaran I tried everything. Then there was a virus that was not letting me shutdown the pc. Then I decided to hard reset my Laptop .Now everything is fine.

Comment: Damn !! I don't want to reset my laptop.. thanks for the update though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

`⋮` > `Settings` > `Search engine`

If the search engine is labeled **Bing**, then click on the dropdown and select **Google**

Other methods to try:-

- `⋮` > `Settings` > `Advanced` > `Reset and Cleanup` > `Restore settings to their original defaults` > `Reset Settings`
- Uninstall and reinstall chrome
- Clear cache

Comment: it did not work,https://go.mktsrc.com/ is directing the bing searches